# DataFrame from list of dicts of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `list` of `dicts` where each key in the `dict` contains another `dict`:

```
In [256]: data_list
Out[256]: 
[{'1111': {'index': 602, 'prop_1': 0, 'prop_2': 1},
  '2222': {'index': 602, 'prop_1': 0, 'prop_2': 1}},
 {'1111': {'index': 603, 'prop_1': 0, 'prop_2': 0},
  '2222': {'index': 603, 'prop_1': 1, 'prop_2': 1}}]

In [257]: index = {i.pop('index') for x in data_list for i in x.values()}

In [258]: df = DataFrame(data_list, index=index)

In [259]: df
Out[259]: 
                             1111                          2222
602  {u'prop_1': 0, u'prop_2': 1}  {u'prop_1': 0, u'prop_2': 1}
603  {u'prop_1': 0, u'prop_2': 0}  {u'prop_1': 1, u'prop_2': 1}
```

How can I create the following or similar `pandas.DataFrame`?

```
index1 index2    prop_1    prop_2
602    1111      0         1
       2222      0         1
603    1111      0         0
       2222      1         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you can transform a series of dictionaries into a multiple columns data frame by doing `.apply(pd.Series)`, you can `stack()` your original data frame to a multiIndex Series and then use `.apply(pd.Series)`:

```
df.stack().apply(pd.Series)

#            prop_1  prop_2
# 602   1111      0       1
#       2222      0       1
# 603   1111      0       0
#       2222      1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(key) for key in data_list], axis=1)
       .T
       .set_index('index', append=True)

df.index = df.index.swaplevel(0,1)
df.index.names = ['index1','index2']
print (df)
               prop_1  prop_2
index1 index2                
602    1111         0       1
       2222         0       1
603    1111         0       0
       2222         1       1
```